# Accessing two methods from different files

Tags: php

I am in the process of streamlining my code. As such, I have split my one big class in two. Now there is one class for everything related to connections. On the other class, I have my methods for various operations (select, delete lala)

Where I am a little confused is how to use both classes at the same time. For example, use the variable passed to the connection class and then pass it to the operations class for doing stuff.

See here, this is an example of how I am currently trying to do it.

```
$db1 = new qcon(); //access the connection class
$helper = new dbfunctions(); //access operations class
$db1->openDB(); // Open database method on connection class
$helper->getResult(); //access SQL select method on operations class
$result = db1 + helper; // pseudo code for what I am trying to do here. Put both operations into one variable. Or do I need to do this as an array?
```

Can you help find a fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give this a shot ...

$variable= $this->variable + $variable->variable;

That should work.

Comment: You'd be adding a resource to a result set. How would that work? At best, you'd get an integer back, which in no way represents the objects it was calculated from...

Comment: No, for the reason I mention in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379577/accessing-two-methods-from-different-files/18380016#18380016) below. You can't add a cat and a dog and expect to get a catdog, even if that was a cool cartoon. In C++ you could implement an `operator+()` that could take both operands and add them into something sensible but PHP can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even want two completely different results in *one* variable? It makes no sense, especially since one of the two represents a connection object and the other a result set. It's like you're putting both a car and a truck into a car shaped hole and expect both to come out unscathed.

You either need separate variables (which makes more sense) or if need be an array. Note that even an array makes no sense because you're putting completely different data into both of the indexes you'd be filling.

My guess is that you want this so you can put it in a single return value. That is why references exist. Look up how to pass variables by reference, it will solve your problem if this is why you need it.

Answer (score 0):

try `$result = $this->db1 + $this->helper;`

hope it was helpful. :)